# Difference in placement of "try" keyword

Tags: swift, try-catch

I have a global variable of audio player.
What's the difference between placing try word before the variable initialization

```
do{
   try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURL)
}catch {}
```

and placing try before calling the constructor

```
do{
   audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURL)
}catch {}
```

Of course two cases above haven't any compilation errors.
Thanks

Comment: I would suggest that first case tries assigning and second tries initiating. But I am not sure, just guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no practical difference. As [said by the language guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/in-out-expression) (emphasis mine):

> When the expression on the left hand side of a binary operator is
>   marked with `try`, `try?`, or `try!`, that operator **applies to the
>   whole binary expression**. That said, you can use parentheses to be
>   explicit about the scope of the operator’s application.
>
> ```
> // try applies to both function calls
> sum = try someThrowingFunction() + anotherThrowingFunction()
>
> // try applies to both function calls
> sum = try (someThrowingFunction() + anotherThrowingFunction()) 
>
> // Error: try applies only to the first function call
> sum = (try someThrowingFunction()) + anotherThrowingFunction()
> ```

Just like `+`, assignment is also a binary operator. Therefore, when you say

```
do{
   try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURL)
}catch {}
```

The `try` applies to *both* expressions `audioPlayer` and `AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURL)`. The lone expression `audioPlayer` *cannot possibly* throw an error here – therefore the `try` in this case only applies to the call to `AVAudioPlayer`'s `init(contentsOf:)`, which *can* throw.

The derivation [of the grammar](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/zzSummaryOfTheGrammar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH38-ID458) for this is:

```
//           "try"          "audioPlayer"     "= AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURL)"
expression → try-operator­opt ­prefix-expression ­binary-expressions­opt

prefix-expression → prefix-operator­opt ­postfix-expression
postfix-expression → primary-expression­
primary-expression → identifier­ generic-argument-clause­opt
identifier­ → // matches "audioPlayer" (I'm not going to fully derive this bit further)

binary-expressions → binary-expression ­binary-expressions­opt
binary-expression → assignment-operator ­try-operator­opt­ prefix-expression
prefix-expression → prefix-operator­opt postfix-expression
postfix-expression → initializer-expression­ // matches AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURL)
```

When you say

```
do{
   audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURL)
}catch {}
```

You're using the fact that the assignment expression [has the grammar of](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH32-ID385):

```
binary-expression → assignment-operator ­try-operator­opt ­prefix-expression­
```

As you can see, the `try-operator` can *also* appear on the right hand side of the operator here, and therefore will apply to the `prefix-expression` – which in this case is `AVAudioPlayer.init(contentsOf:)`.

So in both cases, you're catching the error potentially thrown from `AVAudioPlayer.init(contentsOf:)`. The first example just includes the possibility of an error being thrown from the expression on the left hand side of the operator, which it *cannot possibly* do.

Use whichever you feel more comfortable with – my personal preference, and the option which is more consistent with the placement of `try` in other places in the language, is to put the `try` on the right-hand side.

Comment: Great explanation. Those coming from languages with exceptions may assume that `try` has some deep significance, marking where a longjmp goes or other "exception" implementation detail. It's useful to keep in mind that Swift exceptions are just a fancy version of `return`. The `try` has no impact on the compiler or code generation. It's purely there to remind the programmer that this block of code may throw exceptions. Once the compiler feels the `try` is close enough to provide that reminder, it's happy. :D

Comment: Actually this is not quite true. There are situations where a `try` at the start of the line will not compile. I think the fact that it ever does compile is a bug.

Answer (score 2):

In my view, the fact that this compiles is kind of a bug:

```
try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURL)
```

Basically, you're doing something you shouldn't do, and you're just lucky that it slides past the compiler here. Consider, as a counterexample, what would happen if `audioPlayer` were being declared here:

```
try let audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURL) // error
```

That *doesn't* compile, and the Fix-It correctly moves the `try` to where it belongs:

```
let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURL)
```

The rule that I recommend following, therefore, is that you should use `try` placement *correctly* — it modifies the method call that can throw. It may sometimes work for an assignment as a whole, but not always, and it's a bad habit to get into.

Comment: That's a slightly different thing though – that's a binding. If you take a look in the [grammar for a constant declaration](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID355), there's no room for a `try` until the expression on the right hand side of the `=`. Although I agree that the rules are inconsistent, and that `try` on the rhs is preferable :)

Comment: @Hamish Right, I'm just trying to inculcate the notion that "`try` at the start of the line" is _not_ generally okay. If I thought it would do any good, I'd file a bug on this, but I know it wouldn't. :)

Comment: `try` always prefixes an *expression* (not a method call). That's why it's legal to prefix the assignment which is an expression of type `()` or `Void`. It is not necessary for `try` to immediately prefix the throwing part of an expression. Your example `let audioPlayer = ...` is a declaration and so cannot be marked with a `try`.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe I'm with you, but I'm saying it would be a good habit if the expression in question were the expression immediately containing the method call, rather than the whole assignment.

Comment: I agree that it's good style to make the try scope as small as possible. I wanted to make clear that 1. it's not a bug and 2. try does not modify individual method calls.